# Probability that N i.i.d. draws from a multinomial distribution have made all events appear

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, coupon-collector

Consider a multinomial distribution $\mathbb{P}$ on $S$ states $\{s_1,\dots,s_S\}$ where $S\in \mathbb{N}$ and $S\geq 2$, with probabilities $\mathbb{P}(s_i)=:p_i$.  Now consider $N$ i.i.d. draws $X_1,\dots,X_N$ from $\mathbb{P}$ and suppose that $N\geq S$.  What is the probability that *each state has occured?*

So far I have
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\forall s\in S\, (\exists X_i)\, X_i=s\right) = 1- \mathbb{P}(\exists s\in S \, s\not\in \{X_n\}_{n=1}^N)...
$$
But I'm completely stuck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [coupon collector’s problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) with unequal probabilities. You can find lots of questions and answers relating to this problem under the tag [coupon-collector](/questions/tagged/coupon-collector).

By [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the probability that each state has occurred after $N$ draws is

$$
\sum_{A\subseteq [S]}(-1)^{|A|}\left(1-\sum_{k\in A}p_k\right)^N\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks for letting me know its name!  This is very useful.  I never had heard of this problem before.

Comment: @BLBA: You're welcome. You might also want to take a look at the collection of variants of this problem in [this answer on the meta site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382) (under "Coupon collector's problem").

Comment: How beautiful!!

Comment: @joriki Thanks so much for the link.  I will definitely do that.

Comment: @joriki I'm reading abit about the coupon collector problem and I'm wondering, are there simple concentration estimates on $P(\tau>x)$ where $\tau$ is the stopping time which the collector collects all the coupons in $S$? (here $x\geq [S]$).

Comment: @BLBA: I don't know of any, but [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2239126) has asymptotics of the distribution of $\tau$ that might be relevant.